# What happens when a nemesis god is responsible for resurrecting your character?

Tags: dnd-4e, roleplaying

The characters in my group are currently level 24. My character died and got resurrected as a Revenant. (which was planned). The only one participating in the ritual was Vecna, (he told the other party members to step outside) and he used Raise Dead to perform the resurrection. My character worships Corellon and Sehanine. Vecna is our archenemy-we all have good reasons to kill him, and we will try if given the chance.

However. are there any rules about what happens to the subjects of a god if the god is slain or in other ways defeated? Are there any rules about what would happen to my character and other undead related directly or indirectly to him, if he dies? and what would happen to all the secrets he is hiding?

For the role playing part: Being reborn as a [Revenant](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4spot/20090515) directly by the wish and might of a god is a pretty huge deal, even if said god is your enemy. What part of a nemesis god would/could you add to your character without ruining the fun? Are there any rules for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is, I don't believe there are any rules that will affect your character should Vecna die.

From reading the Divine Power handbook, if Vecna were to die and he was the god you worship, any feats pertaining to his domain (i.e. undeath) wouldn't work.  However, you don't worship him, so his death shouldn't impact your character.

I also don't see any rule that would cause your character's death should Vecna die.  A revenant is both living and dead so your character should keep on living. Vecna did a raise dead ritual. There is also nothing saying that your life is tied to Vecna's because he did a ritual to resurrect you. Theoretically, anyone could have done this ritual. (a powerful mage, etc.)

Lastly, there are other gods that are related to undeath. Should Vecna die, I'm sure the argument could be made that one of the other undeath gods would champion you (keeping you alive) as you've essentially strengthened their position for the realm of undeath.

Comment: What other gods is there related to undeath? Raven Queen is the goddess of natural death?

Comment: Although my logic just as easily apply to any god that represents the domain of the living, etc. the following are gods that represent the undeath domain. The Blood of Vol (Ebberon), The Undying Court (Ebberon), Shar (Forgotten Realms), Vecna (Core)